# jquery not working for second time on dynamically created button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jquery function to open the dialog, edit the dialog and send the value back to table(in html page), on button press. These buttons are created dynamically in JavaScript.

Scenario 1: Suppose I created 3 buttons for the first time and then click on any of these three button then jquery executes to open the dialog, read the values and send them to html table row.

Scenario 2: Now when I add some more buttons for the second time, say 2- 4th and 5th button in the same page then on button press of these(4th or 5th) newly created one's, dialog opens reads the value from user, but fail to send it back to the html table row.

How to resolve this issue?

Jquery code:

```
$(document).on('click', "#opener", function () {
    pkg = ($(this).attr('name'));
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    $("#dialog").fadeOut(3000).html(data);
});
```

function to populate the table row(row number to be populated is passed as pkg from js)

```
function PopulateForm(){
    document.getElementById("weight" +  pkg).value=document.getElementById("wt").value;
    document.getElementById("length" +  pkg).value=document.getElementById("lgt").value;
    document.getElementById("width" +  
        pkg).value=document.getElementById("wdt").value;
    document.getElementById("height" + pkg).value=document.getElementById("ht").value;  
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "close" );
}
```

error says for the 4th or 5th button pkg value is not passed.

js function to create the button dynamically:

```
var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
var element5 = document.createElement("input");
element5.type = "button";
element5.setAttribute('id', 'opener');
element5.setAttribute('name', (rowCount+1));
element5.value = 'X';
cell6.appendChild(element5);
```

Comment: Can you console log 'pkg' on click and check once?

Comment: @Aditya pkg is the name value(rowCount+1) that I am passing through the Javascript. While in jquery you can see I am catching it as pkg = ($(this).attr('name'));

Comment: It seems you're creating multiple button elements with the same id:
`element5.setAttribute('id', 'opener');`.  And that seems to be creating conflict with your code... IDs should be unique.  Maybe if you tried something like this? `element5.setAttribute('id', 'opener' + (rowCount+1));`

Answer (score -1):

You could use attribute `"class"` instead of `"id"` for dynamically creating the button and bind it to the event

Also, make sure that you are reloading the `JavaScript` along with the reloaded portion of the page

Comment: Using class instead of id wouldn't be an option if the element is supposed to be unique/uniquely identified